# Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, string-length

I have a JavaScript function:

```js
function addcontent(ele, text, lines, separate_lines){

    if(separate_lines){
    for(i=0; i<lines; i++){
      text=text+"\n"+text+"\n";
    }
  }

    else if(!separate_lines){
    for(e=0; e<lines; e++){
      text=text+text;
    }
  }

    ele.append(text);

  }
```

and when I use it for the onclick of an HTML Button like:

```html
<button onclick="addcontent(document.body, 'A', 100, true)">
    Add content.
  </button>
```

I get this error in the Chrome console when I click the button:

> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length
> at addcontent
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I have no idea where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that on each iteration you add the `text` two times, but you assign the result to `text` again.

- iteration 1: A + A = AA (*but you assign to `text`*) so
- iteration 2: AA + AA = AAAA
- iteration 3: AAAA + AAAA = AAAAAAAA
- iteration 4: AAAAAAAA + AAAAAAAA = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
- etc

So it is exponential. You are basically doing 2<sup>lines</sup> insertion of the text. You can guess that this creates a "quite" large string and it cannot be handled.

Use a different variable for the generated text.

```js
function addcontent(ele, text, lines, separate_lines) {
  let finalText = text;
  if (separate_lines) {
    for (let i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      finalText = finalText + "\n" + text;
    }
  } else {
    for (let e = 0; e < lines; e++) {
      finalText = finalText + text;
    }
  }

  ele.append(finalText);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addcontent(document.body, 'A', 100, true)">
        Add content.
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the old [Wheat and chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem), the string is simply way too long.

You double the string for 100 times that's 2^100...

It works fine with say `lines` = 10

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be resolved if you can do as:

```
text = (text + "\n").repeat(lines * 2);
```

```js
function addcontent(ele, text, lines, separate_lines) {
  if (separate_lines) {
    text = (text + "\n").repeat(lines * 2);
  } else if (!separate_lines) {
    for (e = 0; e < lines; e++) {
      text = text + text;
    }
  }
  ele.append(text);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addcontent(document.body, 'A', 100, true)">
    Add content.
  </button>
```

If you want to add new line in after `A`

```js
function addcontent(ele, text, lines, separate_lines) {
  if (separate_lines) {
    text = `${text}<br>`.repeat(lines * 2);
  } else if (!separate_lines) {
    for (e = 0; e < lines; e++) {
      text = text + text;
    }
  }
  ele.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addcontent(document.body, 'A', 100, true)">
    Add content.
  </button>
```